# numpy array indexing with negative index

Tags: python, numpy

First I have a scalar time series stored in a numpy array:

```
ts = np.arange(10)
```

which is

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Suppose I want to extract from `ts` a series of vectors `(2,1,0)`, `(3,2,1)`, `(4,3,2)`, etc., I can think of the following code to do it:

```
for i in range(len(ts)-2):
    print(ts[2+i:i-1:-1])
```

However, when `i=0`, the above code returns an empty array rather than `[2,1,0]` because the loop body will become

```
print(ts[2:-1:-1])
```

where the -1 in the middle creates trouble.

**My question is**: is there a way to make the indexing work for `[2,1,0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use `None`:

```
ts = np.arange(10)

for i in range(len(ts)-2):
    print(ts[2+i:None if i == 0 else i - 1:-1])
```

Comment: Nice! didn't know I can put a `if...else` there

Comment: not directly related to the question, this does not work in Cython

Comment: wdg, the if-else-construct is for using it inline

Answer (score 3):

This should work too:

```
print(ts[i:i+3][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to do the following

```
slices = np.arange(3)

result = np.array([])
while slices[2] < len(ts):
    # print(ts[slices])
    result = np.r_[result , ts[slices]]
    slices += 1

result.reshape((-1 , 3))
Out[165]:
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```